# how to call server side class method from client side outputstream in core java tcp

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket, tclientsocket

I want to call a method of server side java class from my client side class and pass username password params to it using output stream of client class.

Please let me know how i can achieve it in my code.

below mentioned is my code :

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;

  public class TrialClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Socket socketOfClient = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        BufferedReader is = null;
        final String serverHost = "192.168.9.150";
        String line;

        try {
               // Send a request to connect to the server is listening
               // on machine 'local host' port 7777.            
               socketOfClient = new Socket(serverHost, 9000);

            // Create output stream at the client (to send data to the server)
               OutputStream output = socketOfClient.getOutputStream();
               writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);

               writer.println("username " + "12345");
                writer.println("password" + "abcd");

               // Input stream at Client (Receive data from the server).
               is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketOfClient.getInputStream()));

               System.out.println("username " + "12345");
               System.out.println("password" + "abcd");
               if((line = is.readLine()) == null) {
                   System.out.println("No response from server !!");
               }else {
               while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
               }
               socketOfClient.close();
           } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               System.err.println("Don't know about host " + serverHost);
               return;
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + serverHost);
               return;
           }

    }

  }
```

and here is the method that i need to call :

public java.lang.String casLogin(int username, java.lang.String password)

Parameters:
username - type int - mso username
password - type String - mso password

Comment: create a rest service.

Comment: i cant i only know the ip address and port number of the server..for rest service ill need the entire url @Stultuske

Comment: You can't control what the server does with the data sent by the client unless you control the server code. If you also implement the server and don't want to stick to something like a rest service you need to figure out your own "protocol" which allows you to call a certain method on a specific input.

Comment: i dont have access to the server side apis and hence cannot do anything to that code.the only thing i can do is create a connection with the server and call the server methods through the connection......is it possible to call the server methods through the client code's output stream ?? @DrHopfen

Comment: In my opinion not. Unless the implementor of the server side tells you what to send to do so. That is called a protocol. As a simple example of such an protocol and how stuff could work you can have a look at smtp (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example).